# getting git: Breaks: gitosis trying to install both to ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, git

following the instructions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Git), I run the command

```
sudo apt-get -y install git-core gitosis
```

and get

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  git: Breaks: gitosis (< 0.2+20090917-7) but 0.2+20090917-2 is to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

No idea how to proceed.  Any ideas much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gitosis is obsolete, use [Gitolite](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/)